# What would be the return type of DataTable for custom method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, restsharp

Initially, I have consumed REST API in C# and converted the response into a `DataTable`.

```
namespace pg
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            data1();
        }

        public static void data1()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/");
            var request = new RestRequest("giveData");
            var response = client.Execute(request);

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string rawResponse = response.Content;
                var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(rawResponse);
                DataTable dt = root.notifications.ToDataTable();

            }
        }

        public class Rootobject
        {
            public List<Notification> notifications { get; set; }
            public class Notification
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
                public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
                public string email { get; set; }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class IListExtensions
    {
        public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this IList<T> list)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
                dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);

            if (list == null)
                return dataTable;

            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor property in properties)
                row[property.Name] = property.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }
    }
}
```

I will add a new method to my code to do some operations and for that, I require the method data1() to return the DataTable. My question is what return type should I specify for data1() method, which will return me the DataTable 'dt'?

I tried to change the return type of data1() to DataTable but I get error- " Program.data1(): Not all code path return a value".

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        data1();
        newMethod();
    }

    public static DataTable data1()
    {
        var client = new RestClient("https://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/");
        var request = new RestRequest("giveData");
        var response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string rawResponse = response.Content;
            var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(rawResponse);
            DataTable dt = root.notifications.ToDataTable();
            return dt;

           else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ErrorMessage);
            }
       }

    }

    public static void newMethod()
    {
            operations...
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error has nothing to do with the data type (which is fine), but with the fact that you only return a data table in the `if`. What "if not"? You cannot return "nothing". You could make DataTable nullable and return null, or your could throw an exception. But you cannot just leave your compiler hanging here. *You* have to define what happens "if not".

Comment: I have added an else statement, in case i do not receive a response. While in the debug mode, I do get a response from the api but the issue is with the return type of the function. I am going to return the DataTable(dt) but I get error if I specify the return type as Datatable.

Comment: @Mav That is *because you still not return anything in case of the "else"*. Your `else` block needs either a `return` or a `throw`, this has nothing to do with data tables, this is basic program flow.